# sql injection in no sql db azure table

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Like SQL injection, is it possible to have a sql injection in azure table which is a no sql database. I do not have any specific example but is there a way through which a rogue data can create security risk in the table.

Comment: Hi, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. It would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

`no sql database`(like azure table storage) still has the risk of sql injection.

There're some examples and some ways to prevent it, you can refer to the links below for more details:

[SLD Injection, it’s a thing](https://wesleycabus.be/2016/04/sld-injection-its-a-thing/)

[How the prevent Azure table injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702074/how-the-prevent-azure-table-injection)